# Cannot read property 'LoginName' of null

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery, people-picker

I am getting this error when i am trying to get value of people and display on a dashboard. Please let me know what would be the cause of this error.It has the value in list and checked the internal name is correct.
[image: I am getting this error]

Comment: we'll need to see that `getUserById()` function code. Also I see the request is passing an object, you should be passing a number to that first error GET Uri.

Answer (score 0):

I see the request is passing an object, you should be passing a number to that first error GET Uri. We probably need to see your code to know more.